# What Delta-V can I gain from very low thrust exit from EML-5 by gravity assist from Earth to Mars?

Tags: delta-v

My vehicle can exit Earth - Moon L-5 point by very low thrust and enter Earth fly-by to Mars. I am not concerned about the time for this maneuver, but say at least 80 days. What Delta-V can be gained from the fly-by? Say Delta-V direct from EML-5 to Mars is 1.9km/s using vehicle propellant. and if I can gain Delta-V from Earth fly-by I can save on propellant.
I have searched and found many documents but they are very complicated and I request a reference or answer that I can follow. I am not too concerned about accuracy at my stage of conceptual design, I am more interested in the approach and then to use this for insertion into Mars capture with Delta-V estimate.

Comment: Does the Earth flyby entail leaving the Earth-Moon system for some period of time then flying by Earth enroute to Mars, or lowering "directly" from EML-5 to an Earth flyby?

Comment: Could you add links to some of the "many very complicated documents"?

Comment: To BrendanLuke  Leave Earth-Moon system with low thrust (low acceleration low propellant use) and go "directly" from EML-5 to Earth flyby to gain delta-v to reduce propellant use.

Comment: To BrendanLuke, Its a large robotic vehicle assembled at EML-5, so not low thrust but low acceleration. Time to enter Earth flyby not important at this stage. Need a easy routine to try out scenarios.

Comment: Semantic quibble: Choice of maneuver doesn't gain you delta-V; it allows you to spend less (or more) of the Delta-V you have when going to your intended destination. It would be like saying "I got extra gas by deciding not to detour through Mexico City  when driving from San Francisco to Los Angeles." Your delta-v is a function of your engine design, the mass of your rocket, and the fuel you have available.

Answer (score 2):

None.

At EML5, you are balancing close to the boundary of the Earth-Moon system, being close to escaping with zero excess velocity.

But to reach Mars, you need an excess velocity of close to 3km/s.
There is no flyby manoeuvre that can gain you this excess by flying past the central object of the very system you are trying to escape, it's the same reason why a Sun flyby does not make sense even if it is the most massive body in the solar system.

Lifting you orbit to close to escaping the Earth, and then dropping the periapsis down to near the Earth, you can achieve some excess speed by flying past the Moon on the outbound leg. But this extra speed is not enough to reach Mars.